# What to do "which stylesheet format would you like to use (use arrow keys) " in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm creating an Angular project using angular cli and they are asking me "which stylesheet format would you like to use (use arrow keys)" with different formats.

Why is this appearing?

Comment: For styling the application, stylesheets are used. The types of the stylesheets are scss and sass. You may use any of them for styling

Comment: When that question is asked, just press the return key. That way you will choose the default which is css.

Comment: When that question (I mean the one above) is asked I would recommend reading what is browser and how it works. I mean, if you don’t know what is css probably you should learn it before angular

Comment: I'd recommend selecting SASS. It's backwards compatible with CSS and it has a ton of awesome features.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Angular CLI provides an interactive experience in some cases.  Although you can avoid this by passing in the style flag documented in the angular docs here: https://angular.io/cli/new.  If you don't pass in a style sheet you just need to press the up or down arrows to decide which format you prefer

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what it says on my screen.

Comment: That is exactly what it says on my screen.  Unfortunately, that does not give me any information as to what these options mean.  For beginners (especially since CSS is a known standard), the recommendation is to use CSS for now.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to use your keyboard arrow button < ,^, > ... for choosing your options.

Comment: Welcome to SO, are you able to supply a reference for that ?